# Are noise cancelling headsets safe?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life, biophysics, noise, laboratory-safety

Older microlight headsets such as the [Lynx Micro System](http://www.lynx-avionics.com/English_Site/E_Site_Products/E_Products_Micro_Files/e_micro_headset_home.html) are modelled on ear defenders and physically attenuate the noisy cockpit environment by clamping hard onto your noggin. Most modern GA headsets (e.g. [Bose A20](https://www.bose.co.uk/en_gb/products/headphones/aviation_headsets/a20-aviation-headset.html)) seem to be built with far less attenuation, don't clamp on as hard, and tend to rely on ANR features rather than isolating the ear.

Naively, it seems that this would pump more audio power into the ear? Granted, it will be in opposition to the original noise, but it seems it would be very tricky to get the cancellation exactly in phase. **Is there a risk that using ANR and less attenuation would not be as effective in preventing ear damage as passive attenuation?**

Comment: I'm voting this week as off topic because it is about the safety of headphones and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Maybe if the OP rephrased the question to ask about "audio power" rather than "safety"?

Comment: Lolz, off-topic on aviation.stackexchange.com, off topic on physics.stackexchange.com. I think there's a reason I stopped using these sites...

Comment: These things are typically tested by health and safety types.  You have to put your trust in them, and your question probably ought to be such a body.

Comment: @Mat: each site has a [tour] page that describes what is on topic, perhaps you should peruse that before complaining?

Comment: "Are they safe?" is a medical or regulatory question. "What is the power spectrum at the eardrum?" is a physics question. The latter feeds into the former, so physicists are involved, but as asked this isn't a physics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't pump more power into the ear.

The cancellation isn't nearly as "tricky" as you think it is. The frequency range over which cancellation occurs is typically from about 100 Hz to a few kHz - see for example this graph from http://www.michaeldwarren.com/tag/headphones/page/11/

[image]

You can see that there is some variability in the effectiveness. But if you consider that the speed of sound is about 340 m/s, at 10 kHz the wavelength of sound is only 3.4 cm - roughly the distance from the diaphragm to your ear. At that distance, the cavity of the headphones almost become a resonator, and you need to roll off the frequency response (of the cancellation).

But in the intermediate range, you can get robust cancellation of 20 dB or greater for most frequencies. The A20 is supposedly even better, but I don't have hard data to back that up.

The point is - you are not "pumping in more power", you are effectively "removing" power by adding a negative-pressure component as a positive-pressure wave approaches your ears, and vice versa.

In my experience, with normal (QC15) noise cancelling headphones, when a commercial plane is landing and has to put full reverse power, I can hear distortion (clipping) from the noise cancellation circuit (perhaps because the batteries run flat after a long flight). At that point, they are probably not doing much good. I assume the A20's are better for that.

As for your final question "is there a risk"? Yes - if the batteries run out, the A20's will be a lot less effective than the passive cups.